# Will I be able to upgrade to iOS 7 on iPod Touch 4G?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I bought an iPod touch 4G and I'm looking forward to iOS 7... until I read on [this site](http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/10/ios-7-supported-devices/) that it is only compatible with the iPod Touch 5G. Does that mean that I'm "Out in the woods" for security? Or does this just mean I don't get the new Airdrop, iTunes Radio, and camera filters?

I don't mind that much that I don't get the new look (although if I could, it would be nice), but I just want my device to be secure.

The thing that I don't get about this is Apple supported the iPhone 3GS up until now (It is three models old), but when another device is one model old, "No! We can't support this device!" Apple could be changing it's views on how to run their business so they make more money, but I like my iPod Touch just fine. In fact, I like the older design better and I can't see running out to the store to spend 300 bucks to get a design I don't like as much just to have a security upgrade.

Comment: Do you have any sort of article or research that shows no updates to iOS 6 will be released for security issues? The pattern established is that security updates are provided for n-1 and sometimes n-2 major OS versions depending on how recently the hardware was for sale. In the case of the 4th Generation iPod, they were for sale until recently in 2013 so it would be quite a change (and a little shocking to me) to not have security updates for several years after that particular model was withdrawn from sale.

Comment: Go to apple.com and ios 7 says what it is capable for… I'm sad too because I have an iPod touch 4g and was really waiting for ios 7

Comment: what is this "Security" issue you're talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Towards the end of the WWDC keynote, Craig Federighi showed a slide listing the devices on which iOS 7 would be supported. In the [official keynote video](http://www.apple.com/apple-events/june-2013/), this occurs around the 1:54 mark.

Here’s a picture of the slide:

[image: Screenshot taken from the 1080p iTunes version of the keynote]

It reads:

> iPhone 4 and later
>   iPad 2 and later
>   iPad mini
>   iPod touch (5th generation)

This matches the images and descriptions on the pages for iOS 7 for Apple’s website, so this seems to be the canonical list.

It’s possible that Apple will add support for the 4th generation iPod touch between now and the release, but currently it looks like you won’t be able to upgrade.

Comment: Ha, the photo looks kinda like the guy is singing... weird timing. Ha ha ha. :)

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson: It’s a little known fact that Federighi leads the development of Apple’s software by performing West End musical numbers and interpretative dance. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The public page for iOS 7 shows that the iOS is designed to run on the iPod touch 16/32/64 (and they separate the low end model from the higher two) and there is zero reference to generations.

From the information I've seen that Apple released, we can only assume iOS 7 will support the current for-sale models:

- http://www.apple.com/ios/ios7/features/
- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1353
- http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_ipod/family/ipod_touch_16gb
- http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_ipod/family/ipod_touch

Unless you have a reference to some other details, it's probably too early to expect a detailed list of what models will run an announced. We can edit this as new information arrives or the iOS 7 gets released when there will clearly be an article listing in detail what devices can upgrade and what shipping features support what models.

Also, Apple has a history of issuing security updates for several prior versions of OS and there's nothing concrete to point at. The article you link seems to be reading the tea leaves as I do (looking at the physical pictures to identify the generation of iPod touch, but until there's a public announcement, it's anyone's opinion that can be offered.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, but the iPod Touch 4th gen has 256 MB of RAM while all other devices for iOS 7 have at least 512 MB of RAM... If you want, wait a while or send feedback to Apple, or just buy a new iDevice.

Comment: Why would I pay $300 when I don't want any of the features, I just want security. That is stupid to do.